# Retrieve all records for pdfDocument

Tags: dynamics-business-central

Is it possible to retrieve all records for pdfDocument for parentType =SalesInvoice and not one at a time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/api/dynamics_pdfdocument_get

tried using expand as this seems to work for some other objects
/pdfDocument?$expand=salesInvoice

but id did not work in this case

Can you help?